# Excel Text Split into columns post a semicolon ignoring

Tags: excel

Pretty new to excel VBA and coding, I wanted to get some support with the following text.
I would like to have the following text split into columns.
Usually, the data is always in the same format being a TEXT: TEXT
Name: John Doe

Could someone help me understand how to begin splitting this text into columns? or direct me to a previously answered questions or an online resource. Anything would help

thanks,

```
Name: JOHN DOE
Date: 13-Jan-2020
Issue: HAL BOARD [2,1,0] Error failed to fill
Observation: HAL BOARD [2,1,0] Error failed to fill
Action taken: Safe stopped machine, replaced bank inlet filter
Product Impact: No, No product impacted, safe stopped
Validation Impact : No, repair made to instrument does not impact fit for or function
Verification: Repair made to instrument does not impact product as it is before the depense
Parts: 1 in line filter
Remarks : N/A
Name:JOHN Doewr
Date: 13-Jan-2020
Issue: HAL BOARD [2,1,0] Error failed to fill
Observation: HAL BOARD [2,1,0] Error failed to fill
Action taken: Safe stopped machine, replaced bank inlet filter
Product Impact: No, No product impacted, safe stopped
Validation Impact : No, repair made to instrument does not impact fit
for or function
Verification: Repair made to instrument does not impact product as it is
before the depense
Parts: 1 in line filter
Remarks : N/A
```

Comment: Would you provide a sample where we can see the split pattern to follow, from the data you shared it is not clear to me?

Answer (score 0):

Select the column that has the data, click on Data on the toolbar, then Text to Columns. Select Delimited in the pop-up box and you can then specify what you want to use to separate the text i.e. for every space in the text, put the subsequent text in the next column (which would give you one cell of 'Name:', followed by a cell of 'John' and then another of 'Doe'). Or say for every colon (which would give one cell of 'Name' and another of ' John Doe'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using VB, then you can use "Text to Columns" on the Toolbar|Data for converting text(s) into column(s).

If you mean using VBA then the syntax is as below :

```
Split(expression, [ delimiter, [ limit, [ compare ]]])
```

#the delimiter might be " : " in your case.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) you can read more